# ¿Cómo puedo incluir un controlador en javaFX?

Tags: javafx

recientemente empecé a usar JavaFX para realizar un proyecto, pero el problema llega cuando quiero añadir un controlador en el .fxml. Me da un error en el que me dice que no se ha podido leer la línia 10 del archivo la cual equivale a `fx:controller="clase.del.controlador"` me da un error tipo `javafx.fxml.LoadException` y no se porque sucede ya que en el momento que quito la línea que declara el controlador me desaparece el error y me corre el programa.
Quiero aclarar que puse los .fxml en la directorio resources ya que si los ponía junto con el resto del proyecto, cuando le daba a ejecutar el proyecto con javafx no me los exportaba y me daba error de que no existía el .fxml

Otros datos:
javafx 15.0
Usando maven
java 11

Código del Main (App.java):

```
public class App extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.start();
    File file = new File(App.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()+
            "views/TableroBuscaminas.fxml");

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(file.toURL());
    primaryStage.setTitle(Settings.title);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 400));
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

}

Código del .fxml (TableroBuscaminas.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.input.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/15.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
fx:controller="org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers.TableroBuscaminasController">
   <children>
      <MenuBar layoutX="6.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="607.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <menus>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Jugar">
               <accelerator>
                  <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="J" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
               </accelerator></Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Estadísticas">
               <accelerator>
                  <KeyCodeCombination alt="DOWN" code="E" control="UP" meta="UP" shift="UP" shortcut="UP" />
               </accelerator></Menu>
         </menus>
         <padding>
            <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
         </padding>
      </MenuBar>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="600.0" visible="false" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="44.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="204.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="172.0" text="BUSCAMINAS" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="RED">
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Arial Bold" size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <Button layoutX="122.0" layoutY="248.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="336.0" text="Iniciar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="122.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="122.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="248.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="330.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="44.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="153.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="274.0" text="MIS ESTADÍSTICAS" textFill="RED">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <ScrollPane layoutX="14.0" layoutY="64.0" prefHeight="261.0" prefWidth="544.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
               <content>
                  <AnchorPane prefHeight="257.0" prefWidth="556.0">
                     <children>
                        <Pane prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="553.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="183.0" text="Partidas jugadas:">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="19.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="10">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                        <Pane layoutX="3.0" layoutY="31.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="553.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="183.0" text="Ganadas:">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="19.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="6">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                        <Pane layoutX="5.0" layoutY="60.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="553.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label layoutX="10.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="183.0" text="Perdidas:">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="19.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="4">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                        <Pane layoutX="3.0" layoutY="90.0" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="553.0">
                           <children>
                              <Label layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="183.0" text="Mejor tiempo:">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="19.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                              <Label alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="470.0" layoutY="1.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="76.0" text="22s">
                                 <font>
                                    <Font size="18.0" />
                                 </font>
                              </Label>
                           </children>
                        </Pane>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Código del controlador (TableroBuscaminasController.java)

```
package org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers;

public class TableroBuscaminasController {

    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Initialization code can go here.
        // The parameters url and resources can be omitted if they are not needed
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Unai/IdeaProjects/spigot/BuscaMinas/target/classes/views/TableroBuscaminas.fxml:10
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:945)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:982)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:229)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:754)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2808)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2634)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3323)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3280)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3249)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3222)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3199)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3192)
    at org.brouse.buscaminas/org.brouse.buscaminas.App.start(App.java:27)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers.TableroBuscaminasController (in module org.brouse.buscaminas) because module org.brouse.buscaminas does not export org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers to module javafx.fxml
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:99)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:579)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:938)
    ... 22 more
Exception running application org.brouse.buscaminas.App
[ERROR] Command execution failed.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine (JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute (JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal(DefaultExecutor.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute(DefaultExecutor.java:166)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:504)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXBaseMojo.executeCommandLine(JavaFXBaseMojo.java:394)
    at org.openjfx.JavaFXRunMojo.execute(JavaFXRunMojo.java:100)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
```

Árbol del proyecto

```
-src
  -main
    -java
    -org.brouse.buscaminas
      -controllers
        -TableroBuscaminasController.java
      -App.java
    -resources
      -views
        -TableroBuscaminas.fxml
```

Comment: ¿Tienes que usar módulos de Java 9? Si no, intenta compilarlo con Java 8.

Comment: Buenas, he probado como me has dicho a compilar el proyecto en java 8 en vez de en el 11 pero me sigue dando el mismo problema, es más no me deja usar el module-info que se requiere para compilar javafx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La siguiente línea de la traza del error te indica el problema, y no está en tu archivo `.fxml`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers.TableroBuscaminasController (in module org.brouse.buscaminas) because module org.brouse.buscaminas does not export org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers to module javafx.fxml
```

Como JavaFX necesita acceso reflexivo a tus controladores debes exportar y abrir el paquete que los contiene al módulo `javafx.fxml`. Esto se hace en el descriptor de módulo de tu aplicación (el archivo `module-info.java`).

```
module org.brouse.buscaminas {
    // ...

    exports org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers to javafx.fxml;
    opens org.brouse.buscaminas.controlers to javafx.fxml;

    // ...
}
```

Si quieres estudiar un poco más el tema de la modularidad en Java te recomiendo estos dos artículos.

- [Modularidad en Java 9 (1/2)](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2017/10/30/modularidad-en-java-9-12/)
- [Modularidad en Java 9 (2/2)](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2017/11/16/modularidad-en-java-9-22/)

Comment: Hola, me ha funcionado perfectamente al añadir otra línea más de opens con el nuevo trayecto del paquete que había creado nuevo con otra aplicación, ya que la anterior al crear el proyecto se crearía sola, muchas gracias. Un saludo.